# Making: View {# of entries} in {# of categories with entries}

Tags: categories

Looking to create an overall stat statement that can return these stats:

View {# of entries in channel "distributors"} in {# of categories with entries within channel "distributors"}

Need it to only count the categories that have entries, not the empty ones. I know I can do that first portion, but wonder how to do the second. Also, can't quite figure out what combination of exp:channel tags I'd need to use.

Comment: Here's what I came up with, based on Max's answer:

`{exp:channel:categories channel="distributors" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
        {if count == 1}
        <h2 class="view_areas">
          <a href="#">
            {exp:channel:entries channel="distributors"}
            {if absolute_count == 1}
            View our {absolute_results} distributors in 
            {/if}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            {total_results} states
          </a>
        </h2>
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:categories}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way in this case is use [exp:channel:categories](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#parameters) tag

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="news" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
    {if count == 1} {total_results} {/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: Didn't think to use that if statement to prevent looping, thanks!. Is there a way to count categories that have entries in them?

Comment: Count entries in categories? Or show only not empty (which is already in example)?

Comment: I figured it out. The above code worked!